# Weird Behavior from Console.log() in promises

Tags: javascript, promise, console.log

so I'm doing some work with promises and getting some bizarre behavior when I use the console.log() in the promise.

**CODE**

```
function doSomething(msg){ 
      return new Promise(
        (myresolve, myreject) => {
          setTimeout(
             () => {
              console.log(msg);
              console.log('In the promise')
              myresolve();
            }, 
            1000);
        }); 
    }



   doSomething("1st Call")
  .then(function() {
    doSomething("2nd Call");
    console.log('leaving 2nd promise'); 
  })
  .then(function() {
    doSomething("3rd Call");
    console.log('leaving 3rd promise');
});
```

**OUTPUT to CONSOLE**

- '1st Call'
- 'In the promise'
- 'leaving 2nd promise'
- 'leaving 3rd promise'
- '2nd Call'
- 'In the promise'
- '3rd Call'
- 'In the promise'

**Main Question**
Why is it that JavaScript does not seem to read the lines of code in sequential order once in the promise? It almost seems like it is making a pass first and console logging first, and then going back over the code and executing the functions that are promised to be executed after the .then method. Any insight would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: That is the output I'd expect to see. To help answer your question, can you explicitly list the **exact** output you expect, so we can explain the discrepancy?

Comment: I think you haven't considered the delay caused by the timeouts. P.S. the phrases in your logs `leaving 2nd promise` and `leaving 3rd promise` aren't really accurate. They're within `.then()` callbacks attached to the **1st** promise. They are not dependent on the 2nd and 3rd promises to execute. The 2nd and 3rd promises only cause `2nd call` / `3rd call` and `In the promise` to be displayed.

Comment: code inside setTimeout won't run until later - there's nothing wrong with the order - ... if you put `var ret = doSomething('2nd Call')` and `return ret` after the `console.log('leaving...` you'd get closer to the order you expect

Comment: This is expected with the delay you have set. If you resolve it immediately, you can see that it keeps the order correctly.

Comment: If your `.then()` callbacks returned the Promise instances returned from `doSomething()` the results would be slightly but interestingly different.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys! It was related to the timeout. I wasn't considering that aspect. Nick's answer below is very helpful though. Take care,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
doSomething("2nd Call");
console.log('leaving 2nd promise');
```

Do something is asynchronous and will take `~1000` m/s to finish its execution. So, when `doSomething("2nd Call");` is initially called, your code jumps into your method, returns the promise, and begins the `setTimeout`. Then, `"leaving 2nd promise"` is logged. Later on down the track, the setTimeout that we initiated before by calling `doSomething("2nd Call")` will finish, and so it will log `"2nd Call"` to the console. To wait for your inital call to `doSomething("2nd Call")` to complete, you need to use `.then()` (or `await`) on the promise it returns, such you can execute your code when the promise resolves:

```js
function doSomething(msg) {
  return new Promise(
    (myresolve, myreject) => {
      setTimeout(
        () => {
          console.log(msg);
          console.log('In the promise')
          myresolve();
        },
        1000);
    });
}



doSomething("1st Call")
  .then(() => doSomething("2nd Call"))
  .then(() => console.log('leaving 2nd promise'))
  .then(() => doSomething("3rd Call"))
  .then(() => console.log('leaving 3rd promise'));
```